# Can't assign value to Variable: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, variables, nokogiri

I am completely stumped on this one.

I have the following code:

```
puts block.at_xpath("*/img")["width"].to_i
```

but when I change it to

```
width = block.at_xpath("*/img")["width"].to_i
```

I get this error:

```
NokogiriTUT.rb:70:in `blockProcessor': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

When I have the puts in there it returns the expected value.

**Update:**

```
        def blockProcessor(block)
    header = block.xpath('td[@class="default"]/*/span[@class="comhead"]')
    array = header.text.split
    if array[0] != nil #checks to make sure we aren't at the top of the parent list
        ### Date and Time ###
        if array[2] == 'hours' || array[2] == 'minutes'
            date = Time.now
        else
            days = (array[1].to_i * 24 * 60 * 60)
            date = Time.now - days
        end

        ##Get Comment##
        comment = block.at_xpath('*/span[@class="comment"]')

        hash = comment.text.hash
        #puts hash

        ##Manage Parent Here##

            width = block.at_xpath("*/img")["width"].to_i



            prevlevel = @parent_array[@parent_array.length-1][1]
            if width == 0 #has parents
                parentURL = header.xpath('a[@href][3]').to_s
                parentURL = parentURL[17..23]
                parentURL =  "http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=#{parentURL}"
                parentdoc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(parentURL))
                a = parentdoc.at_xpath("//html/body/center/table/tr[3]/td/table/tr")
                nodeparent = blockProcessor(a) 
                @parent_array = []
                node = [hash, width, nodeparent] #id, level, parent
                @parent_array.push node     
            elsif width > prevlevel 
                nodeparent =  @parent_array[@parent_array.length-1][0]
                node = [hash, width, nodeparent]
                @parent_array.push node 
            elsif width == prevlevel
                nodeparent =  @parent_array[@parent_array.length-1][2]
                node = [hash, width, nodeparent]
                @parent_array.push node
            elsif width < prevlevel
                until prevlevel == w do
                    @parent_array.pop
                    prevlevel = @parent_array[@parent_array.length-1][1]
                end
                nodeparent = @parent_array[@parent_array.length-1][2]
                node = [hash, width, nodeparent]
                @parent_array.push node
            end
        puts "Author: #{array[0]} with hash #{hash} with parent: #{nodeparent}"

        ##Handles Any Parents of Existing Comments ##
        return hash
    end
end
   end
```

Here is the block that it is acting on.

```
 <tr>
    <td><img src="http://ycombinator.com/images/s.gif" height="1" width="0"></td>
    <td valign="top"><center>
    <a id="up_3004849" href="vote?for=3004849&amp;dir=up&amp;whence=%2f%78%3f%66%6e%69%64%3d%34%6b%56%68%71%6f%52%4d%38%44"><img src="http://ycombinator.com/images/grayarrow.gif" border="0" vspace="3" hspace="2"></a><span id="down_3004849"></span>
    </center></td>
    <td class="default">
    <div style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:-10px; "><span class="comhead"><a href="user?id=patio11">patio11</a> 12 days ago  | <a href="item?id=3004849">link</a> | <a href="item?id=3004793">parent</a> | on: <a href="item?id=3004471">Ask HN: What % of your job interviewees pass FizzB...</a></span></div>
    <br><span class="comment"><font color="#000000">Every time FizzBuzz problems come up among engineers, people race to solve them and post their answers, then compete to see who can write increasingly more nifty answers for a question which does not seek niftiness at all.<p>I'm all for intellectual gamesmanship, but these are our professional equivalent of a doctor being asked to identify the difference between blood and water.  You can do it.  <i>We know</i>.  Demonstrating that you can do it is not the point of the exercise.  We do it to have a cheap-to-administer test to exclude people-who-cannot-actually-program-despite-previous-job-titles from the expensive portions of the hiring process.</p></font></span><p><font size="1"><u><a href="reply?id=3004849&amp;whence=%2f%78%3f%66%6e%69%64%3d%34%6b%56%68%71%6f%52%4d%38%44">reply</a></u></font></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you try to add a `puts block` before you call `at_xpath`. Maybe you have a side effect which is changing `block`

Comment: @knut, I just double checked that and that works. Also, it's weird that puts gives me the value I'd expect and want. All I want to do is assign it to a variable.

Comment: What is the context for the `width = ...` assignment and what is `Factory`?

Comment: Factory is a class. The block.at_xpath pulls in the width attribute on an image element.

Comment: Yeah I figured that but what's going on in the method that the assignment is in?

Comment: I updated the question. I think it's pretty straightforward until you get to the 'if w == 0 #has parents' line.

Comment: And which error are you getting, the one in your title or the one in your question?

Comment: The one in the title. The one in the question is because I changed width to w in some instances to try to fix it.

Comment: I have updated the question and the code to reflect reality.

Comment: Can you paste a `block` that raises the problem?

Comment: @Serabe I've updated the post to include the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you don't understand XPath. (You are in good company there; XPath is quite confusing.) Your selectors simply don't match what you think they match. In particular, the one that blows up

```
*/img
```

should be

```
//img
```

or something like that.

Now, *because* the xpath selector doesn't match anything, the value of this Ruby statement

```
block.at_xpath("*/img")
```

is nil. And nil doesn't support `[]`, so when you try to call `["width"]` on it, Ruby complains with a `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass` error.

And as for why it only blows up when you assign it to a variable... yeah, that's not actually what's happening. You probably changed something else too.

---

And now, please allow me to make some other hopefully constructive code criticisms:

- Your question was apparently designed to make it difficult to answer. In the future, please isolate the code in question, don't just paste in your whole homework assignment (or whatever this screen scraper is for).
- It would be extra great if you made it into a single runnable Ruby file that we can execute verbatim on our computers, e.g.:

.

```
require "nokogiri"
doc = Nokogiri.parse <<-HTML
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://ycombinator.com/images/s.gif" height="1" width="0"></td>
  <td valign="top"><center>
    <a id="up_3004849" href="vote?for=3004849&amp;dir=up&amp;whence=%2f%78%3f%66%6e%69%64%3d%34%6b%56%68%71%6f%52%4d%38%44"><img src="http://ycombinator.com/images/grayarrow.gif" border="0" vspace="3" hspace="2"></a><span id="down_3004849"></span>
  </center></td>
  <td class="default">
    <div style="margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:-10px; ">
      <span class="comhead">
        <a href="user?id=patio11">patio11</a> 12 days ago  | <a href="item?id=3004849">link</a> | <a href="item?id=3004793">parent</a> | on: <a href="item?id=3004471">Ask HN: What % of your job interviewees pass FizzB...</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <br><span class="comment"><font color="#000000">Every time FizzBuzz problems come up among engineers, people race to solve them and post their answers, then compete to see who can write increasingly more nifty answers for a question which does not seek niftiness at all.<p>I'm all for intellectual gamesmanship, but these are our professional equivalent of a doctor being asked to identify the difference between blood and water.  You can do it.  <i>We know</i>.  Demonstrating that you can do it is not the point of the exercise.  We do it to have a cheap-to-administer test to exclude people-who-cannot-actually-program-despite-previous-job-titles from the expensive portions of the hiring process.</p></font></span><p><font size="1"><u><a href="reply?id=3004849&amp;whence=%2f%78%3f%66%6e%69%64%3d%34%6b%56%68%71%6f%52%4d%38%44">reply</a></u></font></p>
  </td>
</tr>
HTML

width = doc.at_xpath("*/img")["width"].to_i
```

That way we can debug with our computers, not just with our minds.

- You're writing Ruby now, not Java, so conform to Ruby's [spacing and naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398298/ruby-rails-with-tabs-instead-of-spaces/4401462#4401462): file names are snake_case, indentation is 2 spaces, no tabs, etc. It really is difficult to read code that's formatted wrong -- where "wrong" means "non-standard."
- Everywhere you have one of those descriptive comments (`### Date and Time ###`) is an opportunity to extract a method (`def date_and_time(array)`) and make your code cleaner and easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide so much detail. I really appreciate the points on making me a better programmer. Including the runnable code is a brilliant idea, and I bet 90% of people don't do that. Also, you are correct that assigning the variable isn't the issue. I can make the error appear and disappear by uncommenting and recommenting the line "nodeparent = blockProcessor(a)"